# How to download YouTube videos using YouTube Api

Tags: c#, vb.net, youtube-api

I want to make application that uses YouTube API , but i cant find how to download YouTube videos . Can anyone tell me how ?
By the way I use vb.net & C#.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [Downloading video from YouTube](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube)

Answer (score 2):

Copying audiovisual content is forbidden according to the [YouTube Developer Policies](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies#e-handling-youtube-data-and-content)

> E. Handling YouTube Data and Content
>
> Aside from the permissions and rights granted in this section, you and your API Clients have no further permissions or rights to API Data, including to temporarily stored API Data.
>
> Audiovisual Content
>
> 1. You and your API Clients must not, and must not encourage, enable, or require others to:
>
>    1. download, import, backup, cache, or store copies of YouTube audiovisual content without YouTube's prior written approval,
>    2. make content available for offline playback, or
>    3. use any aspect of the YouTube API Services to facilitate or promote copyright infringement or the exploitation of copyright-infringing materials.

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is not wanted from youtube that videos are downloaded :)  They cannot show ADs once you downloaded it and so on.  It is possible however, you can look at the thread from 2014 here :

[Downloading video from YouTube](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1083164/downloading-video-from-youtube)